# Python end program in shell

Tags: python, shell, unix

I want a script to run an then finish on the python shell with all variables and methods:

```
$ python myprogram.py

...
program output
...

>>>
```

And with #!/usr/bin/python is posible? so I double-click and it just works?

Comment: Why not simply import your module into interpreter?

Comment: I can do a: python -> import myprogramm, but i want to do it straight away

Comment: Did you check `python --help`?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python -i     is the answer

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want Python's `i` flag. From the help menu:

> -i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
>            if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x

So the full command would be

```
python -i yourscriptname.py
```

Comment: bah way better than my suggestion ... how did i not know this after so many years